# PhpStorm автоматически сворачивает комментарии, если с них начать файл. Как это отменить?

Tags: phpstorm

У меня есть файл .js. Начинается он с такого кода:

```
    // ---------------------------------------
    // Добавочная функция JQuery для изменения value, которая вызывает событие change
    // ---------------------------------------
    $.fn.changeVal = function (v) {
        return $(this).val(v).trigger("change");
    }
```

Когда я открываю его, PhpStorm прячет комментарий. Получается вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне это отменить? Сделать так, чтобы он не прятал комментарии?

Comment: File > Settings > Editor > General > Code Folding.

Comment: и там File header. Спасибо.

Comment: Там можете разные типы отключать. Пожалуйста.